# Where can I find the package javax.media.opengl?

Tags: java, opengl, download, package, jogl

I need to import the `javax.media.opengl.*` package.  From [Java OpenGL Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_OpenGL) to http://jogamp.org/, I am sort of confused which download I need. There is a long list of build downloads [here](http://jogamp.org/deployment/webstart/archive/), but they are all .7z files and I am looking for a download usable for a Windows XP 32-bit machine.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You only need two packages for java OpenGL:

```
jogl.all.jar      -> this contains javax.media.opengl.
gluegen-rt.jar    -> this contains com.jogamp.opengl.
Both of which are in here: jogamp-all-platforms.7z
```

http://jogamp.org/deployment/jogamp-current/archive/

**Edit**
They seem to have reorganized their site. I updated the link.

Comment: I fixed the link, they restructured their site. Although, considering that this post is more than a year old, I'm not so sure that jogl.all.jar and gluegen-rt.jar are the only two you need. jogl might have changed in that time and I haven't looked at it in a while. Cheers, Ned

Answer (score 38):

This answer is outdated. JOGL has changed the package name.

`javax.media.opengl` is now `com.jogamp.opengl`

be aware if you have an old project and you try to get the latest library version.

Comment: This change has been done in the version 2.3.1: https://jogamp.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=682

Answer (score 2):

The `7z` archive format can be extracted with [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html), which is available on Windows.

Comment: Even if I am able to extract the files, I am still unsure which package I need and how they are installed.. Hope you can help. Thanks.