# Problems installing JOGL (Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, jogl

after numerous tutorials, I am still unable to install JOGL. I add all of the files into a folder in the class-path then add them to the build-path, but I always get compiler errors.  I have tried both Eclipse and NetBeans, both Windows 7 (64 bit) and Windows 10.  I am fairly new to the world of Java, so please excuse me if this is a fairly simple mistake.
[image: Eclipse screenshot]

Comment: This tutorial is obsolete, it uses an outdated version of JOGL, probably even older than JOGL 1. Use these instructions to install JOGL: http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Setting_up_a_JogAmp_project_in_your_favorite_IDE#Eclipse_IDE_project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to import the `GLCapabilities` class from the correct package. The `javax.media.opengl` package for earlier versions (< 2.3.1), or the `com.jogamp.opengl` for more recent versions. For instance:

```
import javax.media.opengl.GLCapabilities;
//import com.jogamp.opengl.GLCapabilities;
```

...or the entire package:

```
import javax.media.opengl.*;//earlier versions
//import com.jogamp.opengl.*;//
```

See [Bug 682](https://jogamp.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=682) for information on why/when the package was renamed.

Comment: When I add either of those two, I get a "The import javax.media cannot be resolved" error from Eclipse.

Comment: That package should be within the jogl-all.jar. Expand those jar files in the package explorer (left side) to make sure they exist.

Comment: I could not find a javax.media, but I did find a com.jogamp.opengl.GLCapabilities.  When I import it, I resolve a "GLCapabilities cannot be resolved to a type" error, but I still have a "The constructor GLCapabilities() is undefined" error. @copeg

Comment: According to another answer here, jogl may have [renamed their packages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7210194/where-can-i-find-the-package-javax-media-opengl). If you found the right package, great. As for the compiler error - there isn't a no argument constructor of GLCapabilities.

Comment: You were right, the test code I was using was out of date.  I found some more recent code with the new bindings and it worked immediately. Thanks! @copeg

Comment: @copeg Please fix the package name, look at this bug report, we changed it in the version 2.3.1: https://jogamp.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=682